# Blazor - Storing multiple user preferences in local storage

Tags: c#, sql, state, blazor-server-side

I have a dashboard app, that displays certain applications to the user, loaded from the database..

[image]

The tiles are draggable (Jquery).. But im struggling to understand how to move a tile, and then keep the state, so that a user can come back the next day, and still have his preferences.

I have tried to follow Telerik demo, but unfortunately, i am a student, i can't afford the license.. Has anybody done something similar, to keep a users preferences?

Here is the Telerik demo, im struggling with what would be in the models.

Local storage for state

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TelerikBlazorDemos.Services
{
    public class LocalStorage
    {
        protected IJSRuntime JSRuntimeInstance { get; set; }

        public LocalStorage(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            JSRuntimeInstance = jsRuntime;
        }

        public ValueTask SetItem(string key, object data)
        {
            return JSRuntimeInstance.InvokeVoidAsync(
                "localStorage.setItem",
                new object[] {
                    key,
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(data)
                });
        }

        public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(string key)
        {
            var data = await JSRuntimeInstance.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", key);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data);
            }

            return default;
        }

        public ValueTask RemoveItem(string key)
        {
            return JSRuntimeInstance.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.removeItem", key);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part im struggling with.. @Code{ }

```
@page "/tilelayout/persist-state"

@inject LocalStorage LocalStorage
@inject IJSRuntime JsInterop

@using TelerikBlazorDemos.Shared.DemoConfigurator
<DemoConfigurator>
    <DemoConfiguratorColumn>
        <TelerikButton OnClick="@SaveState" Icon="save" Class="mr-xs">Save State</TelerikButton>
        <TelerikButton OnClick="@ReloadPage" Icon="reload" Class="mr-xs">Reload the page</TelerikButton>
        <TelerikButton OnClick="@LoadState" Icon="download" Class="mr-xs">Load last State</TelerikButton>
        <TelerikButton OnClick="@SetExplicitState" Icon="gear" Class="mr-xs">Configure State</TelerikButton>
    </DemoConfiguratorColumn>
</DemoConfigurator>

<div class="demo-alert demo-alert-info" role="alert">
    <strong>Change the Tile Layout</strong> (resize and reorder some tiles, remember their order) and
    <strong>Save</strong> the TileLayout state, then <strong>Reload</strong> the page to see the state persisted.
    <strong>Change</strong> the layout some more and <strong>Load</strong> the state to see the last one preserved.
    You can manage the TileLayout state with your own code to put it in a specific configuration through the <strong>Configure</strong> button.
    This demo will remember your last layout until your clear your browser storage or click the Configure button to put it in its initial state.
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <TelerikTileLayout @ref="@TileLayoutInstance"
                       Columns="3"
                       ColumnWidth="285px"
                       RowHeight="285px"
                       Resizable="true"
                       Reorderable="true">
        <TileLayoutItems>
            <TileLayoutItem HeaderText="San Francisco">
                <Content>
                    <img class="k-card-image" draggable="false" src="images/cards/sanfran.jpg" />
                </Content>
            </TileLayoutItem>
            <TileLayoutItem HeaderText="South Africa">
                <Content>
                    <img class="k-card-image" draggable="false" src="images/cards/south-africa.jpg" />
                </Content>
            </TileLayoutItem>
            <TileLayoutItem HeaderText="Sofia" RowSpan="2">
                <Content>
                    <img class="k-card-image" draggable="false" src="images/cards/sofia.jpg" />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="k-card-body">
                            <p>Sofia is the largest city and capital of Bulgaria. Sofia City Province has an area of 1344 km<sup>2</sup> while the surrounding and much bigger Sofia Province is 7,059 km<sup>2</sup>. The city is situated in the western part of the country at the northern foot of the Vitosha mountain, in the Sofia Valley that is surrounded by the Balkan mountains to the north. The valley has an average altitude of 550 metres (1,800 ft). Unlike most European capitals, Sofia does not straddle any large river, but is surrounded by comparatively high mountains on all sides.</p>
                            <br />
                            <em>* The data used in this demo is taken from <a href="https://wikipedia.com" target="_blank"><em>wikipedia.com</em></a></em>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </TileLayoutItem>
            <TileLayoutItem HeaderText="Rome" ColSpan="2" RowSpan="2">
                <Content>
                    <img class="k-card-image image-center" draggable="false" src="images/cards/rome.jpg" />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="k-card-body">
                            <p>
                               
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <em>* The data used in this demo is taken from <a href="https://wikipedia.com" target="_blank"><em>wikipedia.com</em></a></em>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </TileLayoutItem>
            <TileLayoutItem HeaderText="Barcelona">
                <Content>
                    <img class="k-card-image" draggable="false" src="images/cards/barcelona.jpg" />
                </Content>
            </TileLayoutItem>
        </TileLayoutItems>
    </TelerikTileLayout>
</div>

@code { TelerikTileLayout TileLayoutInstance { get; set; }
            TileLayoutState SavedState { get; set; }
            string stateStorageKey = "TelerikBlazorTileLayoutStateDemoKey";

            async Task SaveState()
            {
                var state = TileLayoutInstance.GetState();
                await LocalStorage.SetItem(stateStorageKey, state);
            }

            async Task LoadState()
            {
                TileLayoutState storedState = await LocalStorage.GetItem<TileLayoutState>(stateStorageKey);
                if (storedState != null)
                {
                    TileLayoutInstance.SetState(storedState);
                }
            }

            void ReloadPage()
            {
                JsInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("window.location.reload");
            }

            async void SetExplicitState()
            {
                TileLayoutState desiredState = GetDefaultDemoState();
                TileLayoutInstance.SetState(desiredState);
                await SaveState();
            }

            protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
            {
                var state = await LocalStorage.GetItem<TileLayoutState>(stateStorageKey);
                if (state != null && TileLayoutInstance != null)
                {
                    TileLayoutInstance.SetState(state);
                }
            }

            TileLayoutState GetDefaultDemoState()
            {
                TileLayoutState defaultDemoState = new TileLayoutState()
                {
                    ItemStates = new List<TileLayoutItemState>()
            {
                new TileLayoutItemState { Order = 1, ColSpan = 1, RowSpan = 1 },
                new TileLayoutItemState { Order = 2, ColSpan = 1, RowSpan = 1 },
                new TileLayoutItemState { Order = 3, ColSpan = 1, RowSpan = 2 },
                new TileLayoutItemState { Order = 4, ColSpan = 2, RowSpan = 2 },
                new TileLayoutItemState { Order = 5, ColSpan = 1, RowSpan = 1 },
            }
                };
                return defaultDemoState;
            } }

<style>
    .k-card-image {
        width: 285px;
        height: 189px;
    }

    .k-card-body {
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .image-center {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

For instance TileLayoutInstance.SetState(storedState); I don't know how this is set up behind the bonnet.
p.s im using .netCore5 and visual studio 2019. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question. Are you using Telerik or are you trying to determine how their example works? If you are coding this from scratch then consider the dashboard as a set of rows and columns or a 2 dimensional array. When the user moves tiles they are switching the location of the tiles within the array. You need to store and maintain the state of the array. A solution can become more complicated depending on if the dashboard is a variable or fixed size. You can store an X and Y coordinate in the model and the tile at the location along with the overall size of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that TileLayoutInstance.SetState expects an instance of TileLayoutState which contains a List of TileLayoutItemState objects. By the look of your example each TileLayoutItemState has an Order property, which determines the order of the object in the TelerikTileLayout component?

When the user moves a tile, you need to save its new position, which presumably your already doing somewhere?
You then save the current order to localStorage and read it back in when the user clicks the Load button.

From the look of it, (and apologies if I misunderstand what your trying to do or I misunderstand how this telerik component works), you then need to re-render the component using the order stored in localStorage. But your rendering code is hardcoded? It adds each TileLayoutItem in a fixed order. I see there is a ReOrderable property which presumably allows this order to be changed, but when the page reloads, I'm pretty sure that it will always render it back in the order you have provided in the HTML.

I think you will need to store the header text, P content and the image name into a list, as well as the order and then use a @ForEach loop around this List (using the correct order which you can control by using LINQ against the order property) to add each TileLayoutItem dynamically, providing the values for the src, headerText properties etc from the iterated object and render it in the persisted order.

Might be easier and more manageable to use a class and save it to a database to be honest.
Also, you can use Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService to read/write local storage without having to write extra JS.